# how to make static factory method for not static instance?

Tags: java, selenium

I have few tests with explicit waits for selenium tests.

I use waiting too much. And I want to move it to base class and cut every time create new object:

> new WebDriverWait(...)

Now it ***looks next***:

```
public void logOutUser() {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='gb_W gbii']")));
    userOptionsMenu.click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div/a[@id='gb_71']")));
    signOutLink.click();
}
```

I want to move it to Base class, and circumvent redundant object creation.

***Base class***:

```
public class AndroidBasePage implements IPage {

    protected WebDriver driver = null;

    private WebDriverWait driverWait;

    public AndroidBasePage() {
        driver = SeleniumManager.activeBrowser();
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public WebDriverWait getWait() {
        if (driverWait == null) {
            driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        }
        return driverWait;
    }
    protected void driverWaitPresenceOfElement(String xpath) {
        getWait().until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
    }
}
```

It ***works now***:

```
public void logOutUser() {
    driverWaitPresenceOfElement("//span[@class='gb_W gbii']");
    userOptionsMenu.click();
    driverWaitPresenceOfElement("//div/a[@id='gb_71']");
    signOutLink.click();
}
```

But I not sure about it efficiency. Any suggestions.

Does exist some way to make `getWait()` static?

Comment: No, because it is different for every instance of the class, you return different WebDriverWait for every instance of AndroidBasePage.

Comment: All this really does is avoid creating a new `WebDriverWait` instance all the time, not sure what else you get out of it.

Comment: @Arran do you know other alternatives for explicit wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did something similar in our Selenium webdriver based project(non Android) years back. using an abstract super class. One of the functionalities was  `getElement(String id/Xpath/name etc)`, which would provide wait implicitly.

for your case I would like to know why you need a factory method? rather make it part of your object instantiation (wait needs your exact driver instance). slightly modifying your class:

```
public class AndroidBasePage implements IPage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    private WebDriverWait driverWait;

    public AndroidBasePage() {
        driver = SeleniumManager.activeBrowser();
         //only one driverwait for a page instance
        driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);//time should be configurable
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }


    protected void driverWaitPresenceOfElement(String xpath) {
       driverWait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a fixed wait time of 30 seconds. Is'nt it better to use implicit wait after you call the web driver initialization?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I did this one. But I have to do explicit as well.